# Why is default constructor required for ServletContextAttributeListener?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I created a class that implemented `ServletContextAttributeListener` without the default constructor and the container complained:

> SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of .....
>   java.lang.InstantiationException: ...

So I created a default constructor in addition to parameterized constructor and everything worked fine.  Since the container requires a default constructs, I suspected that the container is creating a new instance of the class and not using the instance that is already created.  But inserting a static object counter member data, I found this suspicion to be true.

My question is:  If I want to update the member data of my object on `ServletContextAttributeEvent`, can I do it in a thread-safe manner?  What are the side effects of container creating a new object and what are the workarounds?

Comment: Shouldn't attributes have non-default constructor?  Is it a best practice to set attribute member data via setter method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the container instanciates it for you. And yes, this object being unique for the whole webapp (in a JVM), you must make sure everything is done in a thread-safe way, using synchronization. I don't see any side-effect or workaround. That's how it's supposed to be.

You seem to confuse attributes and listeners. You may set and remove any attribute, of any type, to the servlet context. These attributes should **not** implement `ServletContextAttributeListener`.

You may also, on the other hand, register listeners, either via the web.xml, or by calling one of the `addListener` methods of `ServletContext`. Those listeners are **not** servlet context attributes.

If you have registered one `ServletContextAttributeListener` to the servlet context, then each time you set or remove any attribute to/from the servlet context, the listener's appropriate method will be called. The name and value of the attribute that has been set or removed will be inside the event received by the listener.

So, since the container handles several requests in parallel, and since each request may set or remove attributes from the servlet context, the listener will be called multiple times in parallel, and must thus be thread-safe.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of an application wide unique object in a typical eCommerce application?

I was thinking
-  The primary objective is to share an _attribute_ object among different components
-  The secondary objective is to take specific action on _ServletContextAttributEvent_.  

When I have already created an _attribute_ object that I want to share with other components, why should the container create another one?

Comment: @Ravisankar: sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking. A ServletContextListener is an object that is called by the container when an attribute is added, removed or replaced in the servlet context. Each time you call ServletContext.set/removeAttribute(), the listener is called. Either you create it yourself and add it yourself to the servlet context, or you declare it in web.xml, let the container instantiate it and add it for you. In the latter case, you need a default constructor.

Comment: continued :  But in both cases, the instance (created by you or by the container) will receive all the events, and will have to process them in a thread-safe way.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear.  The question is related to ServletContextAttributeEvent and **not** ServletContextEvent.  First I created an attribute and used it in a Servlet.  In the second version, I added a method to this attribute to be invoked when this attribute is added to ServletContext.  What I found is: the Container created a new attribute and called the method from that object instead of from the original object.

Comment: Show us your code. It's impossible to explain how some code works without seeing it.

Comment: Please find the attribute class that later implemented servletContextAttributeListener.

`public class Beer implements ServletContextAttributeListener {  
 private String size;  
 private static int counter=0;     
 public Beer() {  
  counter++;  
 }  
 
 public Beer(String size) {  
  this.size=size;  
  counter++;  
 }     
 public void setSize(String size) {  
  this.size=size;  
 }  
 public String getSize() {  
  return size;  
 }  
 public void attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent   scae) {  
  scae.getServletContext().log("Beer has been added  "+counter);  
 }  
}`

Comment: You seem to confuse attributes and listeners. See my edited answer.